# How to enable HTTPS / Secure access in Apache2 mod_userdir?

Tags: https, apache2, mod-userdir

I would like to enable users of a test server to be able to host content and access them through HTTPS. However, I'm not going to allow everyone to write to the /var/www.
How can I enable the content stored in /home/*/public_html to be accessed with HTTPS?

Answer (score 0):

Install and configure both mod_ssl and mod_userdir.

Comment: How to configure both, in order to work?

Comment: Read the documentation and configure each, they are independent of each other.  For example, EL ships example configs if you install the httpd and mod_ssl  RPMs.